# PostgreSQL Array datatype to JSON object

Tags: arrays, json, postgresql

I'm attempting to output a postgreSQL (ver 11.4) table to a JSON object within a view and one of the columns is an INT array that needs some special formatting.  The array can be of 4 to 10 elements.

If the column (col_arr in the code) contains {2, 4, 6, 8, 9},

I need to output to look like {"option_1" : 2, "option_2" : 4, "option_3" : 6, "option_4" : 8, "option_5" : 9}

I tried about fifty different combinations of function, and the code below is what I came up with that actually produces what I need.  It looks hideous, and I know there's got to be a simpler solution, but I'm at a loss to figure out what it would be.  Any suggestions would be appreciated.

```
SELECT cast('{ ' || string_agg('"' || propname || '" : ' || propval,' , ') || ' }' as json) as col_arr
  FROM (SELECT t.table_id, a.elem as propval, 'option_' || a.nr as propname
        FROM   t_table AS t
        LEFT   JOIN LATERAL unnest(col_arr)
        WITH ORDINALITY AS a(elem, nr) ON true) pt 
GROUP BY table_id
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`json_object_agg()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-aggregate.html):

```
select table_id, json_object_agg(format('option_%s', ord), value) as col_arr
from t_table as t
cross join unnest(col_arr) with ordinality as a(value, ord)
group by table_id
```

[Db<>fiddle.](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=f3bb1a2d7b1539e8b1a67ada7c554c08)

Comment: Maybe even simpler [with a subquery instead of the grouping](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=70d36f7901d62a2005967a9998e49f94)

Comment: My query seems simpler to me, but your solution may be a bit faster indeed.